# Notifications between Pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

**The problem:**

`Websockets` and `Socket.io` allow for rich 2-way asynchronous notifications between client and webserver.

`Socket.io` between HTML/javascript client and ingress "cookie" routing creates a stateful association between a Pod in a Deployment (let's call these pods of Deployment A) and the HTML/javascript client. Other Pods in other Deployments (let call these Pods of Deployment B and Deployment C) may want to notify the specific Pod in Deployment A of events specific to what Pod A is displaying.

Is there a Kubernetes mechanism to allow this registration and communication between pods?

**Generic Setup:**

Deployment A, B, C each have multiple replicas.

The pods from A, B, and C can read and update records in a dumb distributed store.

Each pod from A will be responsible for a set of pages (i.e., webserver). The set of pages that a specific pod A is responsible for can change dynamically (i.e., user decides what page to edit). pod A are not stateless since "cookie" control ingress routing and pod A maintains a `socket.io` to user html/javascript page.

Pods in B or C update components on the pages. If a page component is updated by B/C that is currently being edited by pod in A, the B/C pod must notify the specific pod A of the update.

More than one pod A may be editing the same page.

**More detail:**

Deployment A is a nodejs express server hosting `socket.io` from html/javascript clients. Traffic is routed from an ingress using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"` so the pod hosting a specific client can send unsolicited traffic to the client. i.e., asynchronous two-way traffic.

Deployment B is is a backend for Deployment A. A simple `socket.AF_INET` is opened from a pod in deployment A to a Service for deployment B. Response from B goes to A and then to the client. So far, so good, everything works, but only tested on 1 node configuration.

Deployment C is a backend to Deployment B. A socket is opened from B to a Service for C. Response from C to B to A to the WebClient works fine (again on a 1 node configuration)

**The problem:**

Deployment B and C may get requests from other sources to process information that would change the content displayed to the user. I want to update any pod on deployment A that is hosting `socket.io` to the client displaying this page.

The description/implementation so far does not asynchronously update the pod A unless the user does a full page refresh.

Multiple users may display the same page but be associated via ingress cookies to different deployment A pods.

As it stands now, user 1 only sees updates initiated by user 1, and user 2 only sees updates from user 2. Unless each user does a page refresh.

I want B and C to send updates to all pods in A that are displaying the page being updated.

**Solution that does not feel Kubernetes clean:**

A pod wanting notifications of changes to components on a page would create a record indicating it's interested in changes to this page containing its pod's IP address, and a good until timestamp.

When a client displays a page, the hosting A pods will update a record in the distributed datastore to indicate it wants updates to components on this page. Every so often, Pod A will update the keep alive time in this records.  When the user leaves this page, associated Pod A will remove this record.

Any pod updating records for a page would check this record and open a socket to this other pod to notify it of changes.

An audit would remove any records expired that were not correctly cleanup because of abnormal termination of a pod after it registered its interest in being notified of changes.

**Question Restated:**

Is this a clean Kubernetes solution or is there something in Kubernetes to make this cleaner?

New to Kubernetes: did I mess up Kubernetes nomenclature anywhere in my question?

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to reliably communicate between pods of different Deployments. It's kind of possible in case of StatefulSets where all pods have known and stable names.

In your case, assuming I understand your requirements correctly, I would recommend using queue messaging software like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/)

Comment: If I understand correctly, ip address assigned to pods are routable to all other pods.  Do you know if this is correct?
When a pod is killed or dies, so do the socket.io connections between it and the html/javascript client.
if the above 2 are correct, a pods can communicate with other pods as reliably as a pod can host a socket.io connection to the client html/javascript page.
I am new to Kubernetes so appreciate correction if I got it wrong.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/ says "pods on a node can communicate with all pods on all nodes without NAT".

Comment: Using microk8s Kubernetes, looks like pods stay up for a long time.  Going down only when pods crash or network changes or sw updates to the system. So socket.io between Pods and client html/javascript is quite stable.  Does google Kubernetes also stay up for a long time or do they get reset by the system frequently? In other words, is google Kubernetes stable enough for a good user experiance for applications using WebSockets?  I'm assuming the answer is yes.

Comment: A quick read of RabbitMQ or Kafka: looks like it does the job but a lot more.  For applications like nodejs/express hosted on Kubernetes using WebSockets / Socket.io, I do not see what these give me over simple INET TCP sockets and updating a centralized store to mark interest in communication.  Am I giving Kubernetes too much credit?

Comment: Pods are mortal, they can disappear for whatever reason and a replacement pod created under Deployment knows nothing about state of its predecessor. Pods don't save they IPs or names and Service objects that balance connection to the pods and serve as Service discovery for Pod's Application, forward connection to set of pods randomly (or evenly). StatefulSets on the other side, give predictable names to their pods, and Headless Service can help to connect to a specific pod. It's commonly used for HA stateful application or database pods.

Comment: VAS, Are you suggesting Pods are not suitable for terminating socket.io sessions?  When a Pod dies, regardless of reason, socket.io will drop and get established with a new Pod. This new Pod would then update the datastore identifying that it is hosting the target page.

Comment: Okay, that actually might work well. Basically, your solution is a some kind of replacement for Kubernetes service discovery based on let's say "subscription model". Kubernetes only provide you label based service discovery, which doesn't meet your requirements. So, shared data storage or message queue service would be an optimal solution.